How did 1977's Car Polo arcade game by Exidy perform hitbox detection, and rigid body collision and movement on the ball?
The link here is a youtube video of Exidy's Car Polo from 1977 : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NMljzipOy4s
What blew me away when seeing it in action was the game's hitbox detection for all 4 vehicles simultaneously.
Atop all that, the ball kicked around by the cars attains momentum upon being hit, which slowly degrades while moving over the playfield (due to friction). Not only is this rigid body simulation in action, it also simulates rigid body over a frictioned surface
Considering floating points were a long whiles away, how in the world did the developers pull off smooth speed degradation due to friction and rigid body collisions + hitbox tests? All of these would certainly rely on some form of floating point calculations right? Even with LUTs, there would have been next to no space in memory to handle it, not to mention having to calculate collisions between upto 4 cars at worst case, and the ball having to calculate its resultant direction of movement by being hit by upto 4 cars at once

I adjusted the title to make it clear that you are talking about an Exidy arcace game, not a game that runs on an Exidy Sorcerer home computer.  (With an Exidy being my first computer, that was what I thought you were asking about.)

@RichF same here, so I was wondering a bit when seeing the video :)

Re: "floating points were a long whiles away,"; first published description of floating-point numbers: 1914. First appearance in a computer: 1938. First appearance in a commercial computer: 1942. So, ummm, they were 'a long whiles' away in the sense of being -63 years away? Microsoft also offered a floating-point BASIC for the Altair before 1977, one for the Commodore PET at its 1977 launch, plus versions for the TRS-80 and Apple II in 1978.

@Tommy In that I was referring to floating points being used in real-time scenarios such as video games in a very common manner while still keeping performance relatively good being long away

@Hash even if you attempt to stretch and strain the idiom beyond recognition, games like Lunar Lander go back to at least 1969 in floating-point implementations. Spacwar! is from 1961. I don't know where you've invented your concept of what was and wasn't common from.

@Tommy I'm not really sure what this hostility is about. If you take Hash's meaning to be "fast floating point operations were a ways away", that's CERTAINLY true in 1977 for consumer machines. All those machines you mention had FP available in the environment but how many had fast, dedicated HW for it? At least be right if you're going to be snippy.

@AdamHyland I'm not really sure why you're imagining hostility but noting again: you're cherry-picking a definition of "a ways away" in order to cherry-pick a definition of "fast". Clearly you've decided what conclusion you want to reach and found a way to get there. What proportion of early video games were written purely in BASIC, and what proportion of BASICs were floating-point only? What proportion of mainframe-era games such as Spacewar!, Lunar Lander et al were float-based? Would suggest you adopt a normal definition of 'fast', i.e. 'fast enough to do the task'.

Another famous antecedent: Woz's 1976 floating point routines for the 6502. Which subsequently appeared in the ROM of the 1977 Apple II — and can do massively more than the 1200 operations/second you'd need to do momentum + friction for Car Polo's five objects, despite being optimised for size rather than speed. But I guess they don't count as 'fast' for some pulled-out-of-a-hat reason.

"I don't know where you've invented your concept of what was and wasn't common from" following up a litany where we somehow need to imagine that Zuse was out there deploying FP on a microcomputer seems needlessly belligerent to a new user.  It's reasonable to say "hey, FP was probably not the constraint here" without needing to belabor the point. FP has a long but spotty history prior to standardization and it's reasonable to imagine that 1977 exists prior to widespread adoption of FP in consumer hardware.

Like most games of that era collision detection wasn't done in software or with hitboxes but by the rendering hardware.
I believe Car Polo had 6 hardware sprites (4 players, 1 ball, 1 special). At the beginning of a frame the 6502 CPU is briefly halted while the position of those sprites is copied from RAM to a set of discrete 74161 TTL counters, along with the player rotation information (used to select which bitmap to use for each car).
Those counters then drive the loading and running of shift registers which indicate if the pixel currently being sent to the monitor belongs to one of these sprites (and therefore should be that color). There are also some shift registers for the goals. When more than one of the shift registers outputs a 1 at the same time it triggers an interrupt.
The CPU handles the interrupt, with some memory mapped bits allowing it to determine which 2 objects are colliding. At this point I don't know the exact working but I can make some guesses.
As I said it's an 8-bit 6502 CPU. The program code is also only 4KB in total so there's not much going on. This would indicate that there is no true physics simulation, only a basic state machine that has been tweaked to look good. The fact that there's only one object that actually needs to be simulated (a ball that is conveniently round) and one surface means that things like friction and collisions can be simplified into some very basic vector operations.

The service manual has some details, starting on page 4.  Collision detection (as well as drawing and rotating sprites) is handled with hardware. The software just needs to store the horizontal/vertical locations in memory and the hardware takes care of the rest.
From your video, it looks like there are 8 possible angles for the ball to move. Lookup or calculate the delta x and delta y. Every so often, the horizontal/vertical position of the ball is adjusted by a fixed amount. To simulate friction, slow down how often you update it.

I would've been astonished if the hardware rotated the sprites in 1977. It doesn't. It selects the appropriate pre-rotated image: It then loads the rotation data into the rotation ram to be used in selection of the image to be displayed. Hardware sprite scaling in arcade games appeared around '85 and hardware sprite rotation around '88.

"The processor detects collisions on the screen by the use of interrupts. The outputs of the shift registers are added together in the interrupt detection and conditioning circuitry. If this circuitry detects two or more objects in the same place on the screen at the same time, (example: a car and a car collision) it sends out a pulse which interrupts the processor. The processor, at this time, knows that something has occurred, but doesn't know what. By reading memory location COOO, it receives an eight bit word telling what type of interrupt it was"

@Kelvin Sherlock To slow down how often one would update would still require some form of LUTs since it does not update at a constant rate then right? You would need a LUT to tell you how often to pause/when to update in such a way that the movement of the ball "eases in and out", similar to how one might use a LUT to approximate a Sine

Disassembling and reverse engineering the ROM will give definitive and detailed answers.  In lieu of that, allow me to make some educated guesses.
The short answer is that it is using a lot of tricks and short-cuts to give a reasonable appearance of a rigid body physics simulation.  Also, a 6502 CPU at 0.94075 MHz can do a lot more than one might think.
The graphics circuits on the machine signal whenever the car sprites hit one another or the ball.  That signal is a single bit and is simply on whenever a pixel of one car overlaps another.  This is a far cry from computing overlaps in rotated rectangles.
Watching the game you can see how collisions are resolved by simply backing off the car.  And similarly a collision with the ball will add a bit of velocity to the ball from the car's motion.
The ball itself does move smoothly.  Fixed point math using only add and subtract is all that is needed to handle this.  Most likely it works with 16 bit fixed point with 8 bits of integer and 8 bits of fraction.  Every frame the 16 bit X and Y  velocities will be added to the 16 bit X and Y position of the ball.  The integer part is used to place the sprite which can be done with two instructions as the 8 bit integer value will be a single byte.  It is only 6 instructions to do a 16 bit addition on the 6502.
Friction is simulated by a small reduction of the ball's velocity each frame.  Another two fixed point calculations.  It could even handle friction proportional to the velocity with some kind of power-of-2 division which CPUs in general can do about as quickly as an addition.
All of this is well within the capability of the 6502 in the system as it can easily run thousands of instructions each frame.  It's burden is even less as the sprite graphics hardware means it does not have to draw anything.
Look closely at the video and note how sometimes the ball will move only a little bit when a car hits it and sometimes quite quickly.  Here I imagine they do some simple distance calculation and kick the ball harder when it is closer to the center of the car.  That's quasi-physical as the ball overlapping more of the car suggests they were moving quickly when they collided.  But I imagine it was more for practical purposes to get the two out of collision with each other quickly.  And, no doubt, was just a "feel" sort of thing.  A rule that made the game play and look reasonably.
A proper distance calculation would be expensive even if the square root is avoided and only the X and Y deltas have to be squared.  Those multiplies themselves would be costly.  Not so bad that 3 or 4 per frame would be unthinkable.  But even then a cruder approximation would likely have been used.

It feels like the question is driven by a misconception about games. Games are not about physical correct simulations, but delivering an impression in line with player expectations. That's why cars in GTA explode, roll over, etc. But also why they do not need to have 'hit boxes' or detailed physics simulation.
It's all about making believable scenarios. Same way as a good writer writes a story in a way to let you imagine being a space marine or the lover of the century. It only needs words. Same way a game like above only needs (mostly) 8 bit integer which get incremented, decremented and compared. No fancy physics, no FP. Just delivering expectations.


What blew me away when seeing it in action was the game's hitbox detection for all 4 vehicles simultaneously.

Hit boxes? It's a simple collision check between two sprites. Keep in mind, those are neither 3D nor anything fancy. Just 8x8 pixel. Checking if one car to be drawn shares a pixel with one of the other objects is a simple integer comparison. Executes times amount of cars for each pixel. Something an 8 bit CPU can do tousands per frame. If not further simplified by only checking box coordinates (least 3 bits dropped for rounding) first, then it comes to on check per car per object and only doing pixel checks when a possible collision is near.
That is, if not done by graphics hardware anyway. Like setting an collison flag marker when two sprite pixel would share the same spot. The CPU then just needs to check that flag(s) once per frame when deciding how to draw he next picture - or better how to modify the existing, as such game needs neither double buffering nor rendering. Just outputting a frame buffer.

Atop all that, the ball kicked around by the cars attains momentum upon being hit, which slowly degrades while moving over the playfield (due to friction).

Sure, friction is what it emulates. Practical ball speed is simply two integers (x/y) that get decremented every so and so many frames.

Not only is this rigid body simulation in action, it also simulates rigid body over a frictioned surface

No. That's stuff you do nowadays with more computing power at hand than use cases. Here it's simply collision detection on sprite or pixel level and counting integers.

Considering floating points were a long whiles away,

They were quite common - after all, BASIC is all about FP - but simply not needed at all.

how in the world did the developers pull off smooth speed degradation due to friction and rigid body collisions + hitbox tests? All of these would certainly rely on some form of floating point calculations right?

Why? First of all, FP is only a crutch. A glorified two component integer handling. The kind people use when not really knowing what data (range) to expect. In a game like this the data  ranges are pretty clear:

X = 0 to screen width and
Y = 0 to height.

There will never be a coordinate outside this range (*1) which for this game is defined a a single byte unsigned integer. So everything is just 8 bit increment, decrement or compare. The most basic instructions there are. A 1 MHz 6502 can do about 200,000 per second, or more than 30,000 per frame at 60 Hz. Considering this, it seems obvious that even this little CPU is most of the time doing nothing, waiting for the next frame to start.
Movement of cars and ball is just adding a singed integer to either X/Y position for each car. Let it be a dozend or two in machine instructions per object, already including bound check and acceleration/deceleration. A far cry from what even this little the CPU is capable.
Acceleration/deceleration is no rocket science either. It's just a start value - usually in pixel per frame - or more exact two, one for X one for Y. made as signed 8 bit integer negative goes for up/left, positive for down/right.
Each frame that value gets added to the coordinate resulting in a new position. Acceleration is done by incrementing he speed by 1 until a maximum is reached, or decrementing until it reaches 0 for deceleration (read friction).
For finer granularity, one may use fixed point integer instead. Like counting in 1/8th or 1/16th of a pixel per frame. With a known range, like here, fixed point gives all the advantage of float without the overhead (*2).

Even with LUTs,

Yeah, look up tables are a great way to generate non linear effects (*3)

there would have been next to no space in memory to handle it,

So far a car description is just 4 values:

X/Y position
X/Y movement

That's 4 bytes (or 8 if using sub-positioning *4) plus maybe a flag byte or two. So 512 Bytes of RAM seem quite sufficient to as well do other bookkeeping. The rest is anyway ROM code.

not to mention having to calculate collisions between upto 4 cars at worst case,

Done by hardware, but even if not, it's simply comparingone coordinate per car against 4 others (*5). Also one would of course need to check for hitting a wall, so cars would stop/turn.

and the ball having to calculate its resultant direction of movement by being hit by upto 4 cars at once

Direction an be only one of 8 - maybe 16 - so this is as well just a few 8 bit integer compares and/or additions to find new direction and speed.
No secrets, no rocket science, but a CPU doing nothing most of the time.
Bottom line: It's not what impression a game has to yield, but how that task is executed.

*1 - Fringe cases, which this game will not show, may have to add a sprite wide border in either direction.
*2 - And without any FP errors, as fixed point provides always the same precision.
*3 - Not that a game like that would need it.
*4 - Working with sub pixel positions/speeds may in fact reduce code needed, as one can spare dedicated frame counters and additional tables for special cases.
*5 - Three other cars plus the ball.
